# Quando o propriedade não for int como obrigar o entity a criar um campo na tabela como nullable:false

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

O migration está gerando o campo nome na tabela como **nullable:true** eu não quero que seja true, como eu faço para resolver esse problema?

```
 public class Professor
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Sobrenome { get; set; }
    public IList<ProfessorTurma> Turmas { get; set; }

    public Professor(string nome, string sobrenome)
    {
        Nome = nome;
        Sobrenome = sobrenome;
        //Turmas = new List<Turma>();
    }

    public bool ValidaProfessor()
    { 
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Nome) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Sobrenome)
            || Nome.Any(x => char.IsDigit(x)) || Sobrenome.Any(x => char.IsDigit(x))
            )
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

public partial class TurmaUsuarioProfessorProfessorTurma : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Professores",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                Nome = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                Sobrenome = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Professores", x => x.Id);
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como em C# `string` são sempre do tipo por referencia e com isso eles sempre aceitam valores nulos por serem **nullable**, o EF criar os campos como se aceitassem dados nulos por padrão.

Para colocar obrigatoriedade na propriedade você pode usar o Data Annotation `[Required]` em cima da sua propriedade, ex:

```
public class Professor
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Sobrenome { get; set; }
    public IList<ProfessorTurma> Turmas { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Entendi perfeitamente e coloquei em uso, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @RobsonJunior se a resposta te atendeu, você pode aceita-lá